# Power set equinumerosity. Is this proof correct?

Tags: proof-writing

So I'm trying to prove the following,

> Prove that if $A\sim B$ then $\mathscr{P}(A) \sim \mathscr{P}(B)$.

Here's how I started out to prove there is a function that is injective:

> Suppose $A \sim B$. Then we can choose a function $f:A\rightarrow B$ that
>   is one-to-one and onto. Let's define $H: \mathscr{P}(A)
>  \rightarrow\mathscr{P}(B)$. Suppose $H(A)=H(B)$. Then if $x\in A$ then
>   $f(x)\in H(A)$. Also if $y\in B$ then $f(y)\in H(B)$.

My question is can I say $f(x)=f(y)$ and since $f$ was one-to-one $x=y$. So $H$ is injective.

Here's how I started the proof to show $H$ is surjective. I have no idea about this one:

> To see that $H$ is onto, suppose $y\in\mathscr{P}(B)$ and
>   $x\in\mathscr{P}(A)$. Since $f$ was onto we can choose a $w\in X$ such
>   that $f(w)=z$, therefore $H(X)=z$ as required.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: There are many more elements in the domain of $H$ than just $A$. You seem to not account for the others.

Comment: You didn't define $H$, you only gave its domain and codomain. $H:X\mapsto \{f(a) / a \in X\}$. And I think it'd be easier to build its inverse and prove that it is indeed its inverse instead of proving that it's bijective.

Comment: You need to be specific in how you define $H$, before you can say anything about it.

Comment: So if I define $H:X\mapsto \{f(a) / a \in X\}$ then can I say H(A)=H(B). And continue on with the proof. Also @xavierm02 I have no idea how to build the inverse and prove it as you said. Could you give me some more information.

Comment: $H(B)$ isn't defined. $B\in \mathcal P(B)$ which is the *co*domain of $H$. And to prove that a function is the inverse of another, you just prove that when you compose them (on both sides), you get the identity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By assumption there is a bijection $f:\>A\to B$. We are asked to *construct* a bijective function $H:\>{\cal P}(A)\to{\cal P}(B)$. Your $H$ is coming out of thin air; therefore it's difficult to prove anything about it.

For this construction we should use the given data, namely the information contained in $f$. How could we use this $f$ to produce a map $H$ that operates on subsets $X\subset A$ instead of on points $x\in A$? The most simple and natural thing is to put
$$H(X):=\bigl\{f(x)\in B\>\bigm|\>x\in X\bigr\}\ .$$
In less formal circumstances one would simply write $f(X)$ instead of $H(X)$.

I claim that this $H$ has the desired properties, and leave it to you to provide a proof. There is no new idea needed; just go through the motions.

Let's prove that $H$ is injective! If $X$ and $Y$ are different subsets of $A$ we may assume that there is an $x\in X\setminus Y$. Then $x':=f(x)\in H(X)$, but $x'\notin H(Y)$, because $x'\in H(Y)$ would mean that there is a $y\in Y$ with $f(y)=x'$, and this would contradict the injectivity of $f$. This proves $H(X)\ne H(Y)$.

Comment: Could you at least show me how to do the injective proof?

Comment: Hi could you also add the onto part of the proof so i can compare it with mine? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

A function $f: A\to B$ naturally induces a function $\mathcal P(f):\mathcal P(A)\to\mathcal P(B)$ that will work.

It's really easy, so try to think about it for a minute, but if you need more help:

> Hint: Look at the function that for an element $C\in\mathcal P(A)$ (i.e.
>  $C\subseteq A$) applies $f$ to all elements $c\in C$.

Another hint:

> A function $\mathcal P(A)\to\mathcal P(B)$ takes an element $X\in\mathcal P(A)$ i.e. a subset of $A$, which we can write as $\{a_1, a_2,\ldots, a_i\}$, and gives an element of $\mathcal P(B)$ which we could write $\{b_1, b_2,\ldots, b_j\}$.

Comment: I'm very new to this. I simply cannot think of a function like that. Could you tell me?

Comment: Did you try to see the extra hint? (put the mouse pointer inside the ellow box) - But it's basically what you (tried) to write in you comment above.

Comment: So H(X)=X $\subseteq $A?

Comment: No, you are supposed to use $f$ in the definition of $H$, and the image of $H$ is supposed to be $\mathcal P(B) \not\supset A\supseteq X$.

Comment: Could you give me a full proof if possible?

Comment: It seems to me taht you've been on the right track, bt mostly have had problems formulating it in a way that makes sense, so I've added another hint that I think would be useful.